# Ubuntu 18.04 on vmware ESXi 6.7 and Nvidia - device available, unable to install drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, vmware, cuda, vmware-server

I have esxi 6.7 installed and have my Nvidia Quadro p3200 selected as a pass through on the host.
On the guest, I have ubuntu desktop 18.04
lspci shows me nvidia device
I installed the latest ver 430, and it installed without issues. I also installed cuda toolkit 10.0 without errors.
however, nvidia-smi shows me no devices were found
nvcc --version tells me to install cuda toolkit

when I do sudo prime-select nvidia, it tells me nvidia is already prime

I'm unable to start nvidia-x-server settings either.

I've installed nvidia and cuda on ubuntu without the vm many times, but not sure why this is such a problem. I have tried to do this over a dozen times looking at various help articles. I must be missing some step.

I have installed and reinstalled ubuntu several times on the vm in order to try to get this to work

any help would be appreciated

**Images/screenshots**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJjkv.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUSZa.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PI5Z.jpg

Comment: are you on a wayland session or an X session?

Comment: X session.I also tried doing all the steps via ssh (using Mobaxterm)

Comment: Also, when I do nvidia-smi command it writes this in the logs:

Jun 11 08:58:32 rc kernel: [  109.545932] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x31:0xffff:826)
Jun 11 08:58:32 rc kernel: [  109.545992] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0

Comment: Long shot but I have this issue. Did it ever get resolved?